# iOS: How to to notify a user on reaching near to a store

Tags: ios, geolocation, core-location

I am writing an application that should alert the user on reaching near (with in 300 meters) to a specified retail store.

I am using the API

`[locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:grRegion desiredAccuracy:acc];`

but not able to get the events for enter and exit region.

My Questions are

1. How accurate is this API. Will it me accurate to fire the event if we specify the 300 meter range. Or this event will be fired only when the user changed from one cellular tower to another?
2. If it is not able to get events with in 300 meters, How can I implement my requirement.

PS:- I don't want to use the API `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];` as it would drain the battery quite quickly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to implement `CLLocationManagerDelegate` to intercept the location callbacks for `-didEnterRegion`, and `-didExitRegion`.

I've been using this exact API in my app for almost a year now and I find it to be very accurate with minimal battery drain. I would say this should be your best avenue and wouldn't consider using `-startUpdatingLocation` as it will require a lot more code to implement what you need, not to mention the battery hit.

Implement the delegate and methods, you should be good to go. You can test it out using the location changes in the simulator too. Get things working good before you test them out in real world use.

Comment: I am registering all the delegates yet i am not receiving the call back. When i read some blog, i read that `startMonitoringForRegion` fires only when user change between cell towers.  Ill check my code again to see if anything I'm doing wrong. Thankyou verymuch for the reply.

Comment: -startMonitoringForRegion fires more often than cell-tower transition. The one linked to cell tower is -startMonitoringForSignificantChange. I find the region monitoring to be very, very accurate. It will only fire once you have crossed the boundary though. So if you enable it while you are inside, nothing will happen until you leave.

Comment: Great ! Thats what i wanted. Thanks.